# Establishing a global array of strings

Tags: ios, nsarray

In my app I refer to a number of the same string variables from lots of different view controllers and I have created a number of global `NSString`s using this method:

**OpeningController.h** (before @interface)

```
extern NSString *stringName;
```

**OpeningController.m** (after the @interface {   } @end)

```
NSString *stringName =@"On";
```

I can then refer to/alter *stringName* anywhere in my application.

I want to be able to do the same with an array of strings but when I try the following I get the error *Initializer is not a compile-time constant*.

How do I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

**OpeningController.h**

```
extern NSArray *arrayName;
```

**OpeningController.m** (after the @interface {   } @end)

```
NSArray *arrayName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"String1",
                     @"String2",
                     @"String3",
                     @"String4",
                     nil];
```

Comment: the title is illegible to me ;) but martin is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `openingController` is a class name (hint: it should be `OpeningController`) then you can initialize the array within the class's `+initialize` method, which will be invoked as soon as the class is referenced at runtime:

OpeningController.m:

```
#import "OpeningController.h"

NSArray *arrayName = nil;

@implementation OpeningController

+ (void)initialize {
    arrayName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"String1",
                @"String2",
                @"String3",
                @"String4",
                nil];
}

....

@end
```

EDIT: Note that this isn't a particularly good example as referencing the array *without* referencing `OpeningController` first will access the un-initialized array.  A better approach is a singleton pattern:

OpeningController.h:

```
@interface OpeningController : UIViewController  // Not sure of the subclass

+ (NSArray *)array;

...

@end
```

OpeningController.m:

```
#import "OpeningController.h"

@implementation OpeningController

+ (NSArray *)array {
    static NSArray *array = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"String1",
                @"String2",
                @"String3",
                @"String4",
                nil];
    });
    return array;
}

...

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried this but when I do NSLog(@"Array text - %@", [arrayName objectAtIndex:0]); from a different controller than the OpeningController it says the array is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Yeah `+initialize` won't fire until `OpeningController` is referenced in code.  It sounds like you might want to use a singleton pattern, so you can do `NSArray *array = [ObjectController array];`.  See this article: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: @RichardGriffiths I've updated my answer with a singleton example.

Comment: Thanks for the time you have gone to. I am really struggling to get past the + (NSArray)array; line which causes the error "Interface type 'NSArray' cannot be returned by value" when outside of the {} or "Expected ';' at end of declaration list" when inside the {}.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Arrrrg!  That's cos it should be `NSArray *`!  Fixing now.

Comment: Thanks again. I have got this far and all is fine but I am not sure how to then reference the array. NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]); gives me the error 'Use of undeclared identifier array'

Comment: @RichardGriffiths The array is exposed via the "singleton accessor" (not an offical term), so: `NSLog(@"%@", [[OpeningController array] objectAtIndex:0]);` is what you want.

Comment: Slowly slowly getting there. I have it now so that it works when I put NSLog(@"%@", [[OpeningController array] objectAtIndex:0]); in the OpeningController onLoad but if I put it in any other class it gives the error 'No known class method for selector array'

Comment: @RichardGriffiths And you `#import "OpeningController.h"` in the other class's implementation file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45794/discussion-between-richard-griffiths-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use shared global variables. They create very strong coupling between your different classes, and force all sorts of interdependencies. That leads very quickly to spaghetti-code.

Instead, create a data container singleton. That is a singleton object (do a google search on the singleton design pattern in Objective C, or even search here) that contain properties that you want to share.

Then any time you want to read or write a global variable, you use your singleton's accessor method to fetch the singleton and then invoke the desired property.

NSUserDefaults is an example of a singleton in Apple's frameworks. The code

`[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults]` is a class method call that returns a pointer to the user defaults singleton.

Your code might look something like `[MyDataSingleton sharedDataSingleton]`.

Comment: Thanks Duncan - I have been reading the debate at the bottom of the Matt Galloway article on singletons and there seems to be some question over the method. I am totally new to this so know nothing but wondered if there were any problems with doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You mus init the array, otherwise it will not work.

You can create a instance of the class and get that instance everytime you want.

If you have questions please tell me :)